# Overwritting Attributes of Nodes

Tags: d3.js

Has anyone encountered problems updating the fill attribute of a node. I set the fill value at the start when the nodes are created, and I want to change their color in an 'onClick'. The onclick def works cause I have functionality for doing a translation already working inside it, (so the x and y attributes can be changed)...but for some reason the fill color wont update. It seems to work ok (change the color on click) if i do not set a fill value when setting up my nodes, but I want my nodes to be a specific color so this solution will not work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to say without seeing working code, but could it be that the item to which you're assigning the fill (and the click event) is not the same item that's receiving the initial fill but actually a parent it?

Comment: ya you were right i think, thanks. I ran into a further problem whereby I have a rectangular node, which was listening for the onclick, i then had a text box appended to an 'a' element on this node, and so if you clicked anywhere on the text, the onclick was not executed. This was resolved by placing another invisible rectangle the same size of the node on top of both the node and the text box, and then setting the onclick on this! Anyway, just a heads up if anyone else runs into this in the future. Thanks for the comment!